# Not able to create cross entropy loss in CNTK model

Tags: c++, cntk

I'm trying to follow the example from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tests/UnitTests/V2LibraryTests/RecurrentFunctionTests.cpp) to run a training step on input data in c++. Here's my code:

```
Model::Model(){

    const wchar_t* modelFile = L"./models/final/model.cntk";

    _modelFunc = Function::Load(modelFile, _device);

    _model_input = _modelFunc->Arguments()[0];
    _model_output = _modelFunc->Output();
}


void Model::run_train_step(string &invoked_cmd) {

    const size_t num_targets = targetcmd2index.size();

    auto label_var = InputVariable({ num_targets }, AsDataType<float>(), L"labels");


    // loss and output
    auto xentropy = CrossEntropyWithSoftmax(_modelFunc, label_var, L"xentropy");
```

My app crashes right at that last line. What am I doing wrong? The inference step works just fine, it's only the training step that has a problem.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I trained this in Python with Keras (with the CNTK backend) first before building it into a c++ app.

I caught the exception associated with it (std::logic_error) and this was the result:

- out "Operation 'ElementTimes': Operand 'Placeholder('Placeholder284', [500], [#])' has dynamic axes, that do not match the dynamic axes '[*, #]' of the other operands."    std::basic_string,std::allocator >